# A method to avoid running several regression models?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, modeling, multivariate-analysis, model

Sometimes I have a research question where I have maybe 10 different outcomes and I am interested in whether any of these 10 outcomes are associated with several other variables, such as weight, height, age, sex, alcohol use, symptoms etc.

Now the only way I can answer the question "does any of these 10 outcomes correlate with any of these predictors?" is by running 10 regression models, one for each outcome.

Is there a more elegant way? I've thought of multivariate regression but I'm not sure if it's fitting here?

Comment: That's pretty much what [multivariate regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/254254/28500) does. The regressions for the individual outcomes don't differ, but inference on the models can take into account the correlations among outcome types.

Comment: Would it be correct that I would need to adjust for every p value obtained, for each outcome? The same way I would if I ran 10 models?

Comment: If the question is simply that "does any of these 10 outcomes correlate with any of these predictors?", then I would prefer to do 10 regression models.

Comment: TDT thank you for chiming in. I'm just not sure because the outcomes in this case are a questionnaire questions concerning symptoms and quality of life and they may be correlated (such as memory loss and cognitive decline).

Comment: Maybe describe your actual problem and the data you have rather than theoretical one? If you *just* want to learn about correlation between multiple variables, calculate correlation matrix.