# Does multivariate multiple regression take into account correlated outcomes?

Tags: multiple-regression, multivariate-regression

Thank you so much for your time. I am running an analysis where I explore the association of the same predictors across multiple outcomes (these outcomes are correlated). My understanding is that when I run this in R:

`lm.all <- lm(cbind(outcome1, outcome2, outcome3) ~ age + sex + education, data = df)`

That when using `summary(lm.all)` the output is the same as running multiple univariate regressions (so per each outcome). How do I take into account the correlations between my outcomes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we need multivariate regression (as opposed to a bunch of univariate regressions)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254254/why-do-we-need-multivariate-regression-as-opposed-to-a-bunch-of-univariate-regr) The individual regression coefficients shown by `summary()` are the same as for a set of individual multiple regressions, but the multivariate regression takes the outcome correlations into account, in the coefficient covariances that are needed for accurate inference about their values.

Comment: Unless you have a very large amount of data, you need to propose a model for those correlations in order to estimate them and exploit those estimates in the regression.  `lm` won't do that for you.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. I have a correlation matrix of the outcome variables -- (only two outcomes have a sig. correlation, but biologically it is known that all outcomes are correlated to some extent). Is this what I would need to put into the regression? As a covariate? I'm a bit confused...