# Probing effects in a multivariate multiple regression

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, car

I'm trying to run a multivariate multiple regression in R, i.e. including multiple predictors and multiple outcome variables in the same linear regression model. **Does anybody know how to pull out the coefficients and p-values for the relationship between each predictor and outcome pair in a multivariate multiple regression?** I cannot seem to work out how to do that (I've been trying!).

Let me explain with an example dataset, if it helps:

```
#Create example dataset
df <- data.frame(pid=factor(501), y1=numeric(501), y2=numeric(501), 
y3=numeric(501), y4=numeric(501), x1=factor(501), x2=factor(501), 
x3=factor(501), x4=numeric(501), x5=numeric(501))
df$pid <- seq(1,501, by=1)
df$y1 <- seq(1,101, by=0.2)
df$y2 <- seq(401,201, by=-0.4)
df$y3 <- sqrt(rnorm(501, 7, 0.5))^3
df$x1 <- c(rep(c("sad","happy"), each=250), "sad")
df$x2 <- c(rep(c("human","vehicle","animal"), each=167))
df$x3 <- c(rep(seq(1,10, by=0.1), each=5), seq(1,46, by=1))
df$x4 <- rnorm(501, 3, .24)
df$x5 <- sqrt(rnorm(501, 23, 3.5))
```

I then create the model using this:

```
#Specify the regression model
model <- lm(cbind(y1, y2, y3) ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5, data=df)
```

I can't simply use `summary(lm)` as doing so runs separate regressions without accounting for familywise error, nor does it account for the dependent variables possibly being correlated.

Reiterating my question. **Does anybody know how to pull output so I can work out the coefficient and p-values but doing so in the same model?** For example, I want to work out the coefficients and p-values of:

```
x1, x2, x3, x4 and x5 on y1
x1 and x2 on y2
x1, x2, x3, x4 and x5 on y3
... etc etc
```

I tried the `car` package:

```
modelanova <- car::Anova(model)
summary(modelanova)
```

However, I couldn't get it to break down to a particular outcome variable, it'd only produce coefficients overall (as if a composite outcome variable had been created)

Any ideas would be wonderful. I know I could run several univariate multiple regressions but I am particularly interested in running a single multivariate multiple regression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The p-values are correct - they are the same as when running each of your $Y$s as a separate regression. Check out posts that have been made regarding the purpose of multivariate regression for more details, like [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254254/why-do-we-need-multivariate-regression-as-opposed-to-a-bunch-of-univariate-regr), or [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11127/multivariate-multiple-regression-in-r), or even [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61921/why-is-it-possible-to-have-a-non-significant-manova-but-multiple-significant-uni), but here's a good reference with examples:

https://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendix/Appendix-Multivariate-Linear-Models.pdf

Consider the the setup for linear regression, where $Y$ is $n\times m$ and $X$ is $n \times k$:

$Y=X\beta+\varepsilon$

$\beta=(X'X)^{-1}X'Y$

$\varepsilon=Y-X\beta=(I-X(X'X)^{-1}X')Y$

$\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{\varepsilon'\varepsilon}{n-k}$

Notice that $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is $m \times m$, so its a scalar when $m=1$. To get standard errors of the betas in this case, the formula is:

$\hat{\sigma}_\beta=diagonal(\sqrt{\hat{\sigma}^2(X'X)^{-1}})$

But this doesn't work when $m>1$. To get the same standard errors as running $m$ univariate regressions, you could take the kronecker product like this:

$\hat{\sigma}_\beta=diagonal(\sqrt{\hat{\sigma}^2\otimes(X'X)^{-1}})$

But the advantage of doing multivariate regression is to be able to do combination and joint tests of the betas, like to test whether $\beta_{j,y_1}$ and $\beta_{j,y_2}$ are different from each other. For that, you'll need to do **M**ultivariate **An**alysis **o**f **Va**riance (MANOVA) tests which require the extra information in $\varepsilon'\varepsilon$ and $Y'Y$ to perform.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want a model that treats each outcome separately, maybe [canonical correlation analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation) would suit your situation better? Basically, it builds linear combinations of $Y$ and linear combinations of $X$ such that the correlation between these variates would be maximized. One can then [test the significance of correlation associated with each variate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74470/statistical-significance-in-canonical-correlation-analysis), or induce sparsity to [select the "most important" variables](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.01231.pdf) with LASSO, for example.

R implementations are available in base (well, stats, `cancor`) or several packages (`CCA`, or `mixOmics` for sparse CCA).

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this as an alternative approach. I am still hopeful to use multivariate multiple regression (not just for this problem in particular, but to determine if my suggestion is possible).